# vTestStudio: How do i set the partialPathName in the Diagram?

Tags: tags

vTestStudio has the option to assign a partialPathName value to Transition Elements. The given name then is displayed in bold to the left of the Transition Element, and is used to form the name of the Testcase by stringing all partials on one path together.

I can however find no way to assign this name in the Diagram view, i can only change existing names. A right click on the element only gives the options of edit, delete cut, etc. which also only seem to target the string, not the property itself (i.e. i cannot assign a copied partial to another Transition Element that previously did not display one) - so i only ever have seen those on imported files from external sources.

Can somebody advise?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out myself: The area to the left of the root of a Transition Element, close to the Multiplexer it stems from (of course, where else \s) can be clicked, and an input field for the partialPathName will appear.

Note: setting partialPathNames via editing in the files works too, but can generate errant behaviour if you insert a partialPathName for a Transition Element that does not exit from Multiplexer.